# Create provisioning profile without device with free apple account

Tags: ios, xamarin, provisioning-profile, entitlements

I am working on a Xamarin Forms application.
Everything works well on Android and UWP.
Now, I want to debug my app on IOS.
My application need to use Entitlements.plist, that's why I must have a provisioning profile.
All I have is a Mac and a free Apple developper account.
I've tried some tutorial to generate this profile with XCode but it doesn't works in my case. The error is:

> Failed to create provisioning profile. There are no devices registered
>   in your account on the developer website. Plug in and select a device
>   to have XCode register it.

My problem is that I have no iDevice. So I cannot plug it in... I want to debug my app with the IOS simulator.
How can I add this simulator to my registered devices ?

Comment: Provision profile only for idevice not simulator so you can't

Comment: You **have** to have an iOS physical device in order to get a provisioning profile.

Comment: You don't need a provisioning profile to run on the simulator.  Have you tried to run your project on a simulated device?  No code signing should be needed.

Comment: I have a error message telling me that I have to add a provisioning profile. But if I remove the entitlements.plist file it works on the emulator. But I need to have this file...

Comment: What entitlements are you using.  The free account doesn't work with many of the entitlements: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/device_provisioning/free-provisioning/

Comment: I'm using custom entitlement.

Comment: So, @Ben did you ever figure out how to provision a simulator?

Comment: It's been a long time but as far as I remember, I bought a cheap reconditioned iPhone.